# Re-using Tooltip text

Tags: svg

I have a number of shapes that I want to display browser tooltips when I hover over them. However, because they contain images and caption texts, it means duplicating the same tooltip on each of their contents because they are higher in the Z-Order than the shape.

I was hoping to put them in a <defs> so that I could re-use them. For instance:

```
<defs>
<title id='t1'>This is my tooltip</title>
</defs>

<image ...etc...>
<use xlink:href="#t1"/>
</image>
```

but this doesn't work. Although it sounds like a fairly obvious use-case, I'm guessing that defs only helps with graphic elements. Is that true? Is there another way I can do this?

Comment: defs is not for tooltips. Just repeat the text.

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/defs (under Descriptive Elements) , title elements can occur in defs, so I wasn't sure if it was a bug.

Comment: I have to use this Z-order because the shapes have a background colour, and cannot be in front of the text or image.

Also, the duplication may be significant, If I have a rectangle, say, that includes an image and a caption, and if the image has been automatically resized to fit the available height, then there are three areas where tooltips could be triggered: on the image, on the text, and either side of the image (where the rectangle is still visible).

Comment: Best if you add that markup to the question. A text-only explanation is hard to follow.

Comment: The question is quite well-defined, Robert, IMHO. There's a brief example at https://parallaxview.neocities.org/Images/TreeImage.svg. It sounds like this is a valid real-life use-case that has been missed because it's not about graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same tooltip for my rectangle captions (or any text) is unnecessary if I include the CSS `text { pointer-events: none; }`.

Duplicating the tooltip across the combined shapes can be done by putting a transparent rectangle over them all and giving that a (single instance) tooltip.